# Home directory showing-up twice in Mediawiki links

Tags: mediawiki

I recently installed Wikimedia for a tiny non-profit organization, as I am the technical person on the board.  With this fresh installation links are showing the home directory twice.  Example: (our domain)/~friendso/~friendso/index.php?title=Main_Page .  There must be a simple setting to fix this.  I'm a software dev but new to Wikimedia and honestly while I'm perfectly happy to RTFM, I have no idea where to begin with this.

Answer (score 1):

[`$wgScriptPath`](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgScriptPath) is probably misconfigured.